# How do I add error handling to my code?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make it so the user has 3 chances to enter correct input, and after the 3rd try the program should close and I'll give a custom String. If at any point they enter valid data the program should execute. I would like to add error handling to the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

{

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int month, day; String season = null;
System.out.print("Enter Month & Day: ");
month = in.nextInt(); day = in.nextInt();
if(1 <= month && month <= 3){
    season = "Winter";
    if((month == 3) && (21 <= day))
        season = "Spring";
} else if (4 <= month && month <=6){
    season = "Spring";
    if((month == 6) && (21 <= day))
        season = "Summer";
} else if (7 <=month && month <=9){
    season = "Summer";
    if((month == 9) && (21 <= day))
        season = "Fall";
} else if (10 <= month && month <= 12){
    season = "Fall";
    if((month == 12) && (21 <= day))
        season = "Winter";
}
System.out.println(season);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of adding a try function, but don't know how I'd be able to add it 3 times.

Comment: Can you reformat your code using syntax highlighting?

Comment: Also, this code would not compile as there is no class declaration.

Comment: have a counter. On each attempt `count++` and check `if(count == 3){}`

Comment: @Derek Brown This code does compile, and works with proper inputs. I just don't know how to go about detecting invalid inputs.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev that's how I'm thinking of going about counting the incorrect inputs

Comment: @Ryan What you actually wanted is input valudation, not really error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you. Code is self explanatory.

```
private static final int RETRY_COUNT = 3

retryCount = 0
boolean invalid = true;
while(invalid && retryCount++ < RETRY_COUNT){
   try{
   invalid = false;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)

   .
   .
   .
   }catch(Exception e){
     invalid = true;
   }   
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how i'd implement this, but am a bit confused. Do I have to define RETRY_COUNT to be equal to retryCount?

Comment: RETRY_COUNT  is a constant variable. retryCount will increment after each attempt.